# How to use private key without password in JSch?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I am trying to use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to SFTP a file to a remote location. Per [this article](https://www.goanywhere.com/blog/are-ssh-keys-or-passwords-better-for-sftp-authentication), when you do SFTP, you can use **either**  a private key **or** a password for authentication. We are doing private-key authentication.

JSch has a method called [`addIdentity()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) where you register your private key, but it also takes a password:

> `void addIdentity(String prvkey, String passphrase)`
>
> Adds an identity to be used for public-key authentication.

Does this refer to the private key also being password-protected itself? What if the private key has no password protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a *passphrase* (not a *password*) used to encrypt the private key file.

If your private key is not encrypted, use [the overload that does not take the `passphrase`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-).

```java
public void addIdentity(String prvkey)
```